# Triplicated question:

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

These questions are duplicate of each other:

- [940069](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940069/the-instantaneous-value-of-current-i-amp-at-t-seconds-is-given-by-i-15-sin)
- [926118](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926118/the-instantaneous-value-of-current-i-amp-at-t-seconds-is-given-by-i-15)
- [913917](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913917/the-instantaneous-value-of-current-i-amp-at-t-seconds-is-given-by-i-15-sin)

What should be done?

Comment: In my opinion: The question with no answers should be closed. One of the question has an attempt by the OP as an answer. That one should probably be merged into the one which already has an upvoted answer. (For two of them I voted to close. Only mods can merge questions - so let's wait and see what mods will answer here.)

Comment: After the close votes were cast, both question already entered the review queue: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/268579), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/268587).

Comment: The same person posted the same question three times? He should be taken out and shot. Then we can worry about what to do about the questions.

Comment: The same user has asked a different question twice: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/863550/18398 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/858124/18398

Comment: And also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/824208/a-question-using-arithmetic-progression and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851108/arithmetic-sequence-and-quadratic-equation

Answer (score 2):

If the same question is asked $N>1$ times, choose the best-answered version  and vote to close the other $N-1$ as duplicates of it.

When valuable answers are scattered among the copies, flag for mod attention requesting to merge the questions. (Make sure the merge actually makes sense; if the answers are themselves duplicates of each other, moving them to one place is just busywork.)

---

Meta-point: I suggest asking such questions in a more abstract way, without links (unless a link is necessary to understand what is going on, which is not the case here). The problem is the *meta effect*: questions linked to from meta get disproportionally large number of votes due to extra attention. The votes may be positive or negative; either way, it's a distortion of signal on the main site. Makes the users wonder: [Sometimes I don't get why people upvote some answers so much](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11182/)